# How to supply both passphrase and string to encrypt to GnuPG using command line?

Tags: gnupg, bash

Considering using `echo -n "passphrase" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 ...` inside of Bash script (which should mitigate leaking passphrase to process list given `echo` is a built-in command, right?).

I need to know passphrase to create shares of it using Shamir Secret Sharing later in the script.

How can I supply string to encrypt to GnuPG? I usually use `stdin` for that.

**Edit:** following script appears to achieve what I want, but is it secure<sup>*</sup>?

<sup>*</sup>Passphrase and string are not leaked to other users nor written to file system and passphrase is cleared from memory once script exits.

<sup>*</sup>Script would run as non-admin with `sudo` privileges on read-only offline Raspberry Pi.

**All feedback is welcomed as I might be naively considering an insecure approach.**

```
#! /bin/bash

printf "%s\n" "Please type passphrase and press enter "

read -s passphrase

echo -n "bar" | gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 3 --s2k-mode 3 --s2k-count 65011712 --s2k-digest-algo sha512 --cipher-algo AES256 --symmetric --armor 3<<<"$passphrase"
```

According to `ps ax`, above script doesn’t leak passphrase to other users.

Comment: When you ask "Is it secure?" the counter-question always is "Secure from what?". What is the threat you're worrying about?

Comment: Thanks for helping out @MechMK1. Good point... I am looking for a way to achieve above without leaking passphrase or string to other users and without writing them to file system. I am aware above is likely not memory safe.

Comment: Having a hard time finding good docs for Bash here-string stored in file descriptor. According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/678919) answer, here-strings are usually temporarily written to `/tmp`.

Comment: So, another user on the same machine? Limited? Or with root capabilities?

Comment: @MechMK1 I would like to avoid limiting the scope of this question too much as I am trying to learn as much as possible from you guys... Which threat models are obvious to your give the above script and use case?

Comment: That's the one thing you have to decide. Securing a script running on a machine where you are a limited user, with a potentially adversarial administrator is a *completely* different ball game than a script running on your machine, where you are the admin. And aside from that, limiting the scope of the answer is a *good* thing: It leads to answerable questions. Questions get closed when they are too broad, because answers would need to be as long as a book.

Comment: @MechMK1 Script would run on single-user read-only offline Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Your answers are there:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232063/what-is-most-secure-and-simplest-way-to-have-a-user-typed-password-on-bash-becom

Comment: not so much an answer, but a question: could you solve your problem with asymmetric encryption? if yes, you can quite readily encrypt something using `gpg` that can't be decrypted on that particular host